# Problems after setting up MySQL Cluster on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: sql, cluster

I am fairly new to Ubuntu but I wanted to set up a SQL Cluster. I followed this guide exactly as it says:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04
Only thing that differs is that I downloaded "mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.19-debian9-x86_64.deb" instead of 7.4.11

I got to this step:

> "Enable the startup script and add it to the default runlevels with
>   the command:
>
> sudo systemctl enable mysqld.service"

But then I get this error message

```
Nov 19 18:42:22 MySQL-Server-01 mysqld[25546]: Starting MySQL Nov 19 18:42:22 MySQL-Server-01 mysqld[25546]: .Logging to '/opt/mysql/server-5.6/data/MySQL-Server-01.err'. Nov 19 18:42:23 MySQL-Server-01 mysqld[25546]:  * The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/mysql/server-5.6/data/MySQL-Server-01.pid). Nov 19 18:42:23 MySQL-Server-01 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1 Nov 19 18:42:23 MySQL-Server-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysqld.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed. Nov 19 18:42:23 MySQL-Server-01 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Unit entered failed state. Nov 19 18:42:23 MySQL-Server-01 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Seems like more people has this problem when reading the comments in the guide. 
Do you have any ideas what could cause this? Is the guide outdated already?

Comment: Is your clock really set to November, or is this a very old error message?

Comment: I just copied the fault code from another user in the comments, because I have the exact same error. You can ignore the time stamp.